# Can't import ebooklib: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebooklib'

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

If I type

```
$ pip3 list
```

It returns:

[image: Package list]

So it's clearly installed, yet when I try to import it either in terminal or atom, it returns a module not found error. Every other package like NumPy works perfectly when I try to import.

FIXED:

It was installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

All I had to do was add this line to .bash_profile:
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! It's best to post it as an answer, however—posting answers to your own questions on Stack Overflow is a well-accepted and encouraged practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

All I had to do was add this line to .bash_profile: PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"